# Pixels occupied by a highlighted character in css

Tags: css

I have a box 940px in width and a height of 40px

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>Html Positioning</title>
<style type='text/css'>
.top{
width:940px;
border:1px solid pink;
display:block;
min-height:40px;
}
.orange{
font-size:16px;
background-color:orange;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="top"><span class="orange">v</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the character `v` with a  `font-size 16 px` highlighted and i was wondering how much width and height the character highlighting takes.

I have the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/hzm65/

Does css offer a way of knowing the width and height of such highlighting?.

Comment: Do you have any specific goal in mind? It might help more to tell us.

Comment: There's no way of knowing just with CSS, especially if you're not using a monospace font and the text content is variable

Comment: css is not capable of teeling these things. It's just to assign these properties. If you want to do tricks and getting css properties, then you have to use javascript or some jquery stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By “highlighting”, you apparently refer to giving an element some special background color.

There is no way to know the dimensions in CSS. The width is determined by the metrics of the glyph. The height is determined by the line height of the element (which is in the sample case determined by the browser default line height for the browser default font in the given font size).

In JavaScript, you can query them using the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` properties.